# entity objects where in list

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, list

i followed this tutorial for setting up an upload/download to/from sql database.
http://dotnetawesome.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/how-to-upload-and-download-files-tofrom.html

It works just fine. But i want to modify the populate method so that it will only populate files where the fileid exists within a list that i've stored in session state.

The problem is i've looked around and i can't make any sense of the lambda expressions or work out how to do this.

Basically, i keep a list of the fileIDs in the session, (which is renewed on first page load) so it will only show the files uploaded for that form submission. (it's a claim form)

```
using (Portal_Entities dc = new Portal_Entities()) {
            List<WEBSITE_ATTACHMENTS> allFiles = dc.WEBSITE_ATTACHMENTS.ToList() 
            rptAttachments.DataSource = allFiles;
            rptAttachments.DataBind();
        }
```

I'm guessing i need to put a .Where or .Select on the .ToList here, but i'm not sure.

Like i need a sql type statement where field in ('value','value') where there values come from the list in the session.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
// Get the list of ints called fileIDs that you have stored in session.
List<int> ids = (List<int>)Session["fileIDs"];

// Declare an enumeration in which only the WEBSITE_ATTACHMENTS 
// with an in contained in ids, will be contained.
List<WEBSITE_ATTACHMENTS> allFiles = dc.WEBSITE_ATTACHMENTS
                                       .Where(x=>ids.Contains(x.fileId));
```

Comment: this works perfectly, thanks! I guess it's pretty simply really, but the penny just hasn't dropped with me yet around lambda expressions! Thanks again :)